# XSLT merge two XML files/templates, Getting extra information appended outside the desired tag

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am new to xml and XSLT. I am trying to merge two xml files based on an `id` tag value. I am using xslt version 1.0

Here is my file1.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<people-appointment-data>
<person-data>        
    <id>12345</id>
    <first-name>John</first-name>
    <last-name>Hewitt</last-name>       
    <appointments>
      <appointment>
        <code>1</code>
        <pass>1</pass>
        <states>
            <state>IL</state>
            <state>IN</state>
        </states>
     </appointment>
      <appointment>
        <code>2</code>
        <pass>2</pass>
        <states>
            <state>NV</state>
            <state>CA</state>
        </states>
     </appointment>
</appointments>
</person-data>
<person-data>        
<id>67890</id>
<first-name>Mike</first-name>
<last-name>Hewitt</last-name>       
<appointments>
    <appointment>
        <code>5</code>
        <pass>5</pass>
        <states>
            <state>AK</state>
            <state>MA</state>
        </states>
    </appointment>
</appointments>
</person-data>
</people-appointment-data>
```

Here is my file2.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<people-appointment-data>
<person-data>        
    <id>12345</id>
    <first-name>John</first-name>  
    <last-name>Hewitt</last-name>     
    <appointments>
      <appointment>
        <code>3</code>
        <pass>3</pass>
        <states>
            <state>IL</state>
            <state>IN</state>
        </states>
     </appointment>
      <appointment>
        <code>4</code>
        <pass>4</pass>
        <states>
            <state>NV</state>
            <state>CA</state>
        </states>
     </appointment>
  </appointments> 
</person-data>
<person-data>        
<id>67890</id>
<first-name>Mike</first-name>    
<last-name>Hewitt</last-name>   
<appointments>
    <appointment>
        <code>6</code>
        <pass>6</pass>
        <states>
            <state>AK</state>
            <state>MA</state>
        </states>
    </appointment>
</appointments>
</person-data>
</people-appointment-data>
```

Here is the XSLT I am using.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="lookup-document" select="document('file2.xml')"/>
 <xsl:key name="pdata" match="person-data" use="id" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<people-data>
    <xsl:for-each select="people-appointment-data/person-data">
        <person-data>
            <xsl:variable name="id" select="id" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
            <!--  switch context to lookup-document in order to use              the key -->
              <xsl:for-each select="$lookup-document">
                  <xsl:copy-of select="key('pdata', $id)/appointments/appointment"/>
              </xsl:for-each> 
          </person-data>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </people-data>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is how I am getting the output which is wrong, what is happening is that all the `appointment` are getting appended below the `appointments` tag, but what I am trying to achieve is to actually just copy all the `appointment` that match with the `id` tag inside the first `appointments` tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<people-data>
<person-data>
    <id>12345</id>
    <first-name>John</first-name>
    <last-name>Hewitt</last-name>
    <appointments>
        <appointment>
            <code>1</code>
            <pass>1</pass>
            <states>
                <state>IL</state>
                <state>IN</state>
            </states>
        </appointment>
        <appointment>
            <code>2</code>
            <pass>2</pass>
            <states>
                <state>NV</state>
                <state>CA</state>
            </states>
        </appointment>
    </appointments>
    <appointment>
        <code>1</code>
        <pass>1</pass>
        <states>
            <state>IL</state>
            <state>IN</state>
        </states>
    </appointment>
    <appointment>
        <code>2</code>
        <pass>2</pass>
        <states>
            <state>NV</state>
            <state>CA</state>
        </states>
    </appointment>
    <appointment>
        <code>3</code>
        <pass>3</pass>
        <states>
            <state>IL</state>
            <state>IN</state>
        </states>
    </appointment>
    <appointment>
        <code>4</code>
        <pass>4</pass>
        <states>
            <state>NV</state>
            <state>CA</state>
        </states>
    </appointment>
</person-data>
<person-data>
    <id>67890</id>
    <first-name>Mike</first-name>
    <last-name>Hewitt</last-name>
    <appointments>
        <appointment>
            <code>5</code>
            <pass>5</pass>
            <states>
                <state>AK</state>
                <state>MA</state>
            </states>
        </appointment>
    </appointments>
    <appointment>
        <code>5</code>
        <pass>5</pass>
        <states>
            <state>AK</state>
            <state>MA</state>
        </states>
    </appointment>
    <appointment>
        <code>6</code>
        <pass>6</pass>
        <states>
            <state>AK</state>
            <state>MA</state>
        </states>
    </appointment>
</person-data>
</people-data>
```

This is how I want the output to be. I am not understanding what I am doing wrong. If someone can guide me on this.

Expected Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<people-data>
<person-data>
    <id>12345</id>
    <first-name>John</first-name>
    <last-name>Hewitt</last-name>
    <appointments>
        <appointment>
            <code>1</code>
            <pass>1</pass>
            <states>
                <state>IL</state>
                <state>IN</state>
            </states>
        </appointment>
        <appointment>
            <code>2</code>
            <pass>2</pass>
            <states>
                <state>NV</state>
                <state>CA</state>
            </states>
        </appointment>
        <appointment>
            <code>3</code>
            <pass>3</pass>
            <states>
                <state>IL</state>
                <state>IN</state>
            </states>
        </appointment>
        <appointment>
            <code>4</code>
            <pass>4</pass>
            <states>
                <state>NV</state>
                <state>CA</state>
            </states>
        </appointment>
    </appointments>
</person-data>
<person-data>
    <id>67890</id>
    <first-name>Mike</first-name>
    <last-name>Hewitt</last-name>
    <appointments>
        <appointment>
            <code>5</code>
            <pass>5</pass>
            <states>
                <state>AK</state>
                <state>MA</state>
            </states>
        </appointment>
        <appointment>
            <code>6</code>
            <pass>6</pass>
            <states>
                <state>AK</state>
                <state>MA</state>
            </states>
        </appointment>
    </appointments>
</person-data>
</people-data>
```

Thank you very much for helping.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are copying everything inside "people-appointment-data/person-data" from the first file. Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="lookup-document" select="document('file2.xml')"/>
 <xsl:key name="pdata" match="person-data" use="id" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<people-data>
    <xsl:for-each select="people-appointment-data/person-data">
        <person-data>
            <xsl:variable name="id" select="id" />
            <id><xsl:value-of select="$id"/></id>
            <firstname><xsl:value-of select="firstname"/></firstname>
            <lastname><xsl:value-of select="lastname"/></lastname> 
            <appointments>
              <xsl:for-each select="appointments/appointment">
                  <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
              </xsl:for-each>
              <!--  switch context to lookup-document in order to use the key -->
              <xsl:for-each select="$lookup-document">
                  <xsl:copy-of select="key('pdata', $id)/appointments/appointment"/>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </appointments> 
          </person-data>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </people-data>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have not tested it, so do not argue with me if you need to make same adjustments yet. However, this is the overall idea.

If you want to avoid copying nodes manually, then you need a functionality to copy any nodes except the *appointments* nodes. You can find a discussion about this here:

[XSL: Select all text in a node, except nodes of a certain type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889571/xsl-select-all-text-in-a-node-except-nodes-of-a-certain-type)

Note that doing this way you will be able to copy all the *appointments* preceding nodes at once. After doing so, you can proceed as I have already suggested.

Comment: I understand this is one way to solve it. But in my `xml` data I have more `tags` with reference to the data given in this question such as `firstname`, `lastname`,`age`, `address`....`etc` to type all this data it will be a very big XSLT. I am sure you can do it by copying all the data. I am just not understanding how do I append the data inside the `appointments` tag

Comment: I have added a link to a discussion that may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on `xsl:copy-of` to copy existing nodes, you could make use of the identity template

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then you only need to write a template for the nodes you wish to transform. In this case, you are transforming the `appointments` element in the first document, as you will be adding in the child `appointment` elements from the second document. Therefore, you would have a template like this:

```
<xsl:template match="appointments">
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="../id" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$lookup-document">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('pdata', $id)/appointments/appointment"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This just copies the existing `appointments` element, along with all the child nodes in the first document, and then adds in the `appointment` node from the second document using the key.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="lookup-document" select="document('file2.xml')"/>
    <xsl:key name="pdata" match="person-data" use="id" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="appointments">
        <xsl:variable name="id" select="../id" />
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$lookup-document">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('pdata', $id)/appointments/appointment"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I tried the solution you have recommended, it is not working as expected. It did copy all `appointment` to the merged file under `appointments` tag, but it also copied the `appointment` from first file twice. Can you tell me how to just get this information copied once

Comment: I deleted this line from `<xsl:template match="appointments">`
 Line deleted --> `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>` It works now, I guess that its copying it twice so don't need to apply the identity template. Is this correct?

Comment: When I tried testing it, it produced the expected output shown in your question, so I am not sure what is going on. Have you definitely used the XLST in the answer, or did you make some other changes to it first?

Comment: I am using the one provided in this answer. I copies `appointment` twice this way.  So for the file1.xml you will have duplicate `appointment` tags in the merge